# Infinite loop while displaying SVG, found problem, can't solve

Tags: java, svg, paint, infinite-loop

I have a strange problem. Can somebody tell me why does my void "paint" go into an infinite loop. I checked and it only goes infinite when there is `this.setURI(fi.toURL().toString())` surrounded with `try`/`catch`. When i start the program it prints `svinja` all the time until i close it (that's my test for infinite loop); I'm a beginner and would like the simplest solution. [: Thanks in advance.

p.s. I have all the necessary libraries so that's not a problem.

```
public class SVG_class extends JSVGCanvas {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        System.out.println("svinja");

        super.paint(g);

        File fi = new File("C:\\Users\\Gigabyte\\Desktop\\SVG\\map1.svg");

        try {
            this.setURI(fi.toURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove super.paint(g); ?

Comment: Can we see the code that calls your paint method?

Answer (score 4):

most likely the `this.setURI` results in `paint` being called. Which makes since since it would need to repaint after loading a new model. the solution would be take the `setURI` call out of `paint`.  It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I moved it and it works :D never crossed my mind that could be it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andy if his answer helped you, please accept the answer so others can learn from it just as you have.